# focus go on next textbox only in firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have written code for Preventing an inputbox losing focus when values same in any textbox.which is working fine in chrome and ie but in firefox it looses focus and go to next inputbox.
Here is my code Please suggest suggestions

```
    $('.clsBarcode').bind("focusout", function (e) {

                var repeat = 0;
                if ($(this).val() != '') {

                    var c = $(this).val();
                    $('.clsBarcode').each(function () {

                        if ($(this).val() == c)
                            repeat++;
                    });
                    if (repeat <= 1) {
                        saveflag = false;
                        return;

                    }
                    else {
                        alert("Barcode value exist,Please select different Barcode");
                        $(this).css('border', '2px solid red');
                        $(this).focus();
                        e.preventDefault();

                    }
                }
                else {
                    $(this).css('border', '');

                }


            });
```

Comment: would you provide with jsfiddle link

Comment: jsfiddle link https://jsfiddle.net/aji9/fb3Lq9qq/

Comment: please find the answer below..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please find the solution from jsfiddle link here [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fb3Lq9qq/29/)   . This will work in Internet explorer and firefox.
changed script of yours shown below

```
$('.clsBarcode').each(function () {

   if ($(this).val() == c)https://jsfiddle.net/fb3Lq9qq/28/#run
         repeat++;
     });
   if (repeat <= 1)
    {
        saveflag = false;
        return;

     }
   else {
         alert("Barcode value exist,Please select different Barcode");
         $(this).css('border', '2px solid red');
         var textgroupid= $(this).attr("id");
         setTimeout(function()
         {
             $("#"+ textgroupid +"").focus();
         },10); 
        }
       }
  else {
         $(this).css('border', '');
         //$('#BtnBarcodesave').prop('disabled', false);
       }
       });         
    });
```

Comment: I did but it said  "Thanks for the feedback! Once you earn a total of 15 reputation, your votes will change the publicly displayed post score."